# Django 1.8 AttributeError: module has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, python-import, django-1.8

I was doing an exercise to show "hello world!",but when I open the website,django gave out an exception.What should I do to fix the problem?

The exception is:

```
AttributeError at /
module 'apps.release_news' has no attribute 'urls'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
module 'apps.release_news' has no attribute 'urls'
Exception Location: C:\software\development\PythonProject\DemoGuitarProject\DemoGuitarProject\urls.py in <module>, line 24
Python Executable:  C:\software\development\python3.5\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\software\\development\\PythonProject\\DemoGuitarProject',
 'C:\\software\\development\\PythonProject\\DemoGuitarProject',
 'C:\\software\\development\\python3.5\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\software\\development\\python3.5\\DLLs',
 'C:\\software\\development\\python3.5\\lib',
 'C:\\software\\development\\python3.5',
 'C:\\software\\development\\python3.5\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 2 Dec 2015 15:49:02 +0800
```

My project structure is:

```
DemoGuitarProject
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
apps
  release_news
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  __init__.py
templates
...
```

My urls.py in directory DemoGuitarProject is :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from apps import release_news

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^release_news/', include(release_news.urls)), 
]
```

My urls.py in app directory release_news is :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from apps.release_news import views

__author__ = 'Kami Wan'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),                      
    url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),  
]
```

My views.py file is :

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world ! ")
```

My settings.py file:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'suit',  # admin theme plugin
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.release_news',  # release news
    'django_summernote',  # RTE plugin
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DemoGuitarProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DemoGuitarProject.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# --------------------------------------------user setting area---------------------------------------------------------

# choose a settings file to use
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DemoGuitarProject.settings'

# set the directory for uploading
MEDIA_URL = "upload/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "upload")

# TEMPLATE zh_CN
FILE_CHARSET = "utf-8"
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
```

Comment: @Sayse I tried to delete the secret key just now, but it still doesn't work by  giving the exception:raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

Comment: @KamiWan, @Sayse wanted you to remove the `SECRET_KEY` from the code that you posted, it could be potentially exploited. You should never include sensitive data like this in publicly accessible code.

Comment: @mic4ael,@Sayse  I've done that. Thank you for reminding me this.

Comment: Although you have removed the secret key from your question, it still appears in the edit history. It would be a good idea to change the secret key in your application too.

Comment: No worries, I've removed my comments so there is less tempation for people to go searching around in the edit history at least, I'd encourage all above to do the same. It is also all noise away from your actual question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code from `DemoGuitarProject/urls.py`

```
from apps import release_news
```

read file `apps/release_news/__init__.py`

I guess this file is empty. Add to this file:

```
from apps.release_news import urls
```

or change `DemoGuitarProject/urls.py`

```
from apps.release_news import urls as release_news_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^release_news/', include(release_news_urls)), 
]
```

Comment: Your guess is right and your suggestion really works! I am still confused about why using the statement 'from apps import release_news' can not lead django to find the urls.py file in release_news directory?

Comment: The best place to understand import mechanism: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules